# How To Left Align the Title Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am developing a theme on my website using Thesis 2. I just modified the classic responsive theme.

I created an id using the div tag called "header-middle-sub". And here's the code that I used:

```css
#header-middle-sub {
    background-color: #6699CC;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 897px;
}
```

It works great on a browser using a desktop. But since it is responsive theme, when I open the site in a tablet or mobile phone, the width occupies a fixed 897px.

If I remove this line `width: 897px;` the title is centered on the screen. So what is the code to retain the position of the title?

BTW, here's my website http://bit.ly/1cuTmtE.

Update:

Can anyone please visit my site and use the "inspect element" of chrome or firefox?

Here's the CSS of my header section:

```
.header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
}

#header-top {
    background-color: #7ED7F2;
}

#header-middle {
    background-color: #6699CC;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0f3158;
    border-top: 2px solid #0F3158;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

#header-middle-sub {
    background-color: #6699CC;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 897px;
}

#header-bottom {
    background-color: #0099CC;
}

#header-container {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's the layout on my theme using thesis 2.

[image]

Comment: make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: Please include your CSS and other HTML here. See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

Comment: @jaypabs : For responsive behavior use width in % (percentage) instead of in pixel(px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for desktop too! Make your browser window very small and you will see the horizontal scrollbar. The width is **always** fixed.

To avoid this behavior, use the following css code:

```
#header-middle-sub {
    background-color: #6699CC;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 897px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now, it will always try to stretch the `div` over the whole browser window, but the `max-width` restricts it to 897px, but **less** is **possible**, and **less** will be used on mobile phones or when you resize your browser window.

Comment: BTW, If I have more than 3 menus, the content is overwritten by this menu. Can you help me again resolve this problem?

Comment: May be you mean in the `.main-menu` class. I have already removed it but still it override the content below that menu.

Comment: Oh sorry. It should be remove also at `ul.menu`. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
float: left;
```

read about it here :

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Nice one. Interesting lecture

Answer (score 0):

Try to use float property: `float:left;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ok. I'll do so. At begin this question had other form and common issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries to change the width of the container based on the resolution. And by the way. The problem is that *margin: 0 auto* means: "get my current width and position me in the center with equal margins on the left and right. So, if you want to use margin then you need media queries to dynamically change the container's width.

Answer (score 0):

The property `text-align: left` will work for this, but still it will be clear after some more details of problem or a fiddle